# python lxml with py2exe

Tags: python, xml-parsing, lxml, py2exe

I have Generated an XML with dom and i want to use lxml to pretty print the xml.

this is my code for pretty print the xml

```
def prettify_xml(xml_str):

   import lxml.etree as etree
   root = etree.fromstring(xml_str)
   xml_str =  etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)

   return xml_str
```

my output should be an xml formatted string.

I got this code from some post in  stactoverflow. This works flawlessly when i am compiling wit python itself. But when i convert my project to a binary created from py2exe (my binary is windows service with a namedpipe).I had two problems:

1. My service was not starting , i solved this by adding `lxml.etree` in `includes` option in py2exe function. then on my service started properly.
2. when xml generation in called here, is the error which I am seeing in my log
   `'module' object has no attribute 'fromstring'`

where do i rectify this error ? And Is my first problem's solution correct ?

my xml generation Code :

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from xml.dom import minidom
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, tostring, XML 
import lxml.etree 


    def prettify_xml(xml_str):

      root = lxml.etree.fromstring(xml_str)
      xml_str =  lxml.etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)

      return xml_str

   def dll_xml(status):
    try:
        xml_declaration = '<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>'

        rootTagName='response'
        root = Element(rootTagName)
        root.set('id' , 'rp001')

        parent = SubElement(root, 'command', opcode ='-ac')

        # Create children
        chdtag1Name = 'mode'
        chdtag1Value = 'repreport'

        chdtag2Name='status'
        chdtag2Value = status

        fullchildtag1 = ''+chdtag1Name+' value = "'+chdtag1Value+'"'
        fullchildtag2=''+chdtag2Name+' value="'+chdtag2Value+'"'

        children = XML('''<root><'''+fullchildtag1+''' /><'''+fullchildtag2+'''/></root> ''')

        # Add parent
        parent.extend(children)
        dll_xml_doc = xml_declaration + tostring(root)

        dll_xml_doc = prettify_xml(dll_xml_doc)

        return dll_xml_doc

    except Exception , error:
       log.error("xml_generation_failed : %s" % error)
```

Comment: Does it still happen if you move the import outside of the method definition? And are you sure py2exe is using the same python version as the one you're testing in?

Comment: I tried putting the import outside the function. My service did not start now. I may as well put my code above

Comment: @michael-clerx, i have chaecked my python version and py2exe version , they both are of same type.

Comment: I'm all out of ideas then!

Comment: IIRC you need to include `lxml._elementpath`, but not `lxml.etree`. See http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/WorkingWithVariousPackagesAndModules

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) instead py2exe. I converted your program to binary .exe with no problem just by running `python pyinstaller.py YourPath\xml_a.py`.