# need an xml string with proper indentation in python

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I have generated an xmnlstring. I used lxml and it works properly , but it load fails when converted to py2exe what are the external dependencies. i used minidiom,

```
import mini.dom.minidom
def prettify_xml(xml_str):

   xml_hand =  xml.dom.minidom.parseString(xml_str)
   pretty_xml_as_string = xml_hand.toprettyxml() 

   print pretty_xml_as_string
```

this generates xml in unicode, but i want in a string format.

Comment: But aren't unicode strings strings?

Comment: @Blender but it contains extra characters, which makes parsing fail as my parser is in c and it uses tinyxml. this issue is not seen in lxml. but strangely it fails when it is converted to py2exe

Comment: i have even posted a doubt [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020911/python-lxml-with-py2exe)  yesterday, but it wen unanswered

Comment: You need to escape non-ascii characters. `lxml` defaults to ascii encoding, thus it works.